# Cannot replay sound in J2ME

Tags: audio, java-me, midp, mmapi

I have problem restart sound in J2ME. I want to create player in constructor, then call playExplosion() to play it, but it only plays once. I'm using Wireless Toolkit.

*Sound class*

```
public class Sound () {

    private Player playerExplosion;

    public Sound() throws IOException, MediaException {
        // Explosion
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/explosion.mid");
        playerExplosion = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/midi");
        playerExplosion.realize();
        playerExplosion.setLoopCount(1);
    }

    public void playExplosion() {
        try {
            System.out.println(playerExplosion.getState());
            playerExplosion.start();
        } catch (MediaException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*MyMIDlet class*

```
public class MyMIDlet extends MIDlet() {

    public Sound sound;

    public MyMIDlet() {
        // Init sound object
        try {
            sound = new Sound(this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Test
        System.out.println("Start");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sound.playExplosion();

            // My sound is less than 1 second.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Start
200
300
300
300
300
End
```

For the 1st time, playerExplosion state before start() is 200 (REALIZED).

For the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th times, playerExplosion state before start() is 300 (PREFETCH).

At the moment, I have to create playerExplosion again in playExplosion() method, but it's too slow in a real device.

Answer (score 2):

Try after removing

```
playerExplosion.setLoopCount(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Realizing a Player can be a resource and time consuming process havint to create `playerExplosion` would mean calling `playerExplosion.realize();` again that is why the process takes so much time

When your player is in `PREFETCHED State` what you need to do is just call `playerExplosion.start();` but its not paying again because there is a general limitation on the number of times its should pay

Remove

```
  playerExplosion.setLoopCount(1);
```

And you would be able to pay your file several times

Thanks

:)